# about 2 mirrored pairs in a single ZFS pool

Tags: zfs

If I have 2 mirrored pairs in a single pool, as in: "zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 mirror disk3 disk4", do the 2 pairs form a RAID 0-like configuration? I don't want to have the RAID0 between the pairs, so if disk1 and 2 both fail I still have half my data. By the way, I will be using openZFS on MacOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They form a RAID10 configuration, that means striped mirrors. Each mirror vdev (disks 1+2 and 3+4 in your example) can sustain loss of one disk (for example, disks 1 and 4 may fail without data loss, but not 1 and 2). Therefore, you will not achieve your goal.

Instead you may consider either 4-way-mirrors (losing 75% of space, but having excellent redundancy and very good random read performance), or RAIDZ2 (losing 50% capacity, but allowing any 2 of the disks to die, not specific ones. Note that RAIDZ2 will not nearly perform as well as the other two alternatives, it is ill-suited to random access patterns, while streaming workloads are okay.